# Radio buttons in form builder, when not (directly) mapped to attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, formbuilder, form-helpers

I want radio buttons to update and reflect values that are not directly mapped to an attribute (they are set in a serialized array).

How could I still use the radio buttons in a form builder as the second argument should reflect the value of the attribute in the first argument?

**Update**
This is how a radio_button helper normally is constructed:

```
f.radio_button :my_attribute, false
f.radio_button :my_attribute, true
```

[If the current value of method (`my_attribute`) is tag_value (`false` or `true`) the radio button will be checked.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button)

In my case though, `my_attribute` has multiple values (it's a serialized array). I have tried to put an `attr_accessor` as a placeholder for the attribute, but I would need to pass an argument to it to be able to evaluate it's value :/

**Update 2**
- The iterated collection is categories a user can subscribe to.
- The radio-button pairs are switches to subscribe or not to each category.
- If a category is subscribed to, it's id is inserted in the user's `my_attribute`, and removed if unsubscribed to.
- This procedure is normally done with a join table, but I'd like to save the relationship in an array instead.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what exactly you want, or have you attempted any thing before so please add to the question

Comment: So, let's say `my_attribute` is the array `[A, B, C]`. What exactly do you want your radio button to show? Also, are you talking about the button's _label_ or its _value_?

Comment: The radio buttons (a form actually) are inside an iterated collection `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]`. As `my_attribute` contains `A`, the first iteration should result in a true == checked radio button, while the fourth iteration should show false checked etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood exactly what you want to do but how about something like

```
my_attributes_array.each do |element|
  f.radio_button :my_attribute, element
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but to clarify: with the example data from my comment the enclosing iterated collection has 7 elements. So the page will have 7 pairs (`true` and `false`) of radiobuttons.

Comment: My bad, but it might help if you update your question with the actual setup: Do you have an iterated collection *and* another attribute or is the iterated collection the attribute itself?